# MySQL data source is missing in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

MySQL data source is missing in Visual Studio 2013:

[image: View Picture]

I installed MySQL Connector & MySQL for Visual Studio:

[image: View Picture]

What else should I do?

Comment: Try selecting a different Data Provider in the dropdown from the first screenshot.

Comment: Did you try restarting Visual Studio and/or your system?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes i closed and open.Even i Restart my computer.

Comment: @RossPresser I want to add here like this https://imgur.com/a/bBSwY0D